# Netbeans disable horizontal scroll

Tags: java, netbeans, scroll

Tried the other solutions and can't find the option to line wrap. i never write code with lines this much long and am getting frustrated of that horizontal scroll whenever i try to scroll down and my fingers move even a little bit diagonally.

gif addressing the problem : http://g.recordit.co/dhuj8y0JZP.gif

Comment: i don't really see an issue with the gif tbh.

Comment: @TeoChuenWeiBryan i just did not want such large lines and then allowing to horizontal scroll through them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restart your IDE. You are using a Mac and have probably not closed it for days. This happens when you use the zoom with alt + scroll down

Answer (score 1):

restart IDE. Nothing wrong in preferences.

Comment: @ETrofimov what is the cause of this? what do you mean by restart ID

Comment: oh, sorry, reopen, of cause

Comment: you mean my IDE

Comment: yes IDE, i had the same problem (with vertical scroll),  and fixed it in file->setting-> ... into preferrences, in one word. Are u using 2017 Ide ?

Comment: what does it mean "one word"?

Comment: "In a word", "shortly speaking".. synonims, but may be i wrote this with russian accent